# Charles proxy не работает на Andorid One xiaomi

Tags: android, ssl, proxy, charles

Пытаюсь проксировать трафик с телефона на Android One - Xiaomi a1. Установил сертификат, разрешил везде в настройках эти сертификаты, в самом чарлике подрубил к нужному мне домену SSL проксирование. Но каждый раз, когда трафик начинает идти через charles все ssl коннекты отбиваюся:
Failure SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown

Я ставил сертификат как на Wifi, так и на VPN соединения. Перекачивал его и удалял и ставил заново по несколько раз и т.п. Почему не пускает - не понимаю. На другом андроиде рядом все работает норм, даже на айфоне все настроилось...

Comment: Та же проблема.. удалось найти решение может самому?

Comment: Неа, забил. Использую иос для проксирования терь только)